# How to force set robot arm joint values?

Tags: gazebo, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to test my motion planning, I wish to test from various starting positions in gazebo.  In order to do that, I need to be able to programmatically set the joint values.  How can this be done?

The closest thing I found is the service `/gazebo/set_link_state` but that requires manually specifying the transform of each individual link which seems unintuitive.  Is there a better way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352418/how-to-force-set-robot-arm-joint-values?/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-05-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-15**:
See whether the approach taken in #q352226 works for you.

This won't work if you really *depend* on the state of the Gazebo simulation though. Or at least it may not work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For some reason, `/gazebo/set_model_configuration` (as mentioned in [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/233059/gazebo-set-joint-angles-by-ros/?answer=273254#post-id-273254) didn't work.)

However, I did discover the that `gazebo_ros spawn_model` supports specifying initial joint position.  However, it must be done while physics is paused.

Here's the required snippets of the launch file

```
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" default="worlds/empty.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
</include>

<node name="spawn_gazebo_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -unpause -param robot_description -model robot -z 0.0 -J elbow_joint -1.57" respawn="false" output="screen" />
```

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2020-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0